# I can not understand how to get token out. Authorization on React-Native + Redux

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-native, redux

Good day!
I continue to study redux in conjunction with react-native.

I need to make an authorization. In response to a post-request, a token comes. It (the token) is displayed in the console.
When you output the token using console.log in the component, the token is 'undefined',
I can not understand how to get it out. Where is the mistake? #noob

Use in component:

```
    ...
import { authorization  } from './reducers/authorization';
...
render(){
const {email, password} = this.state;
let {isLoginPending, loginError} = this.props.login;
let { tokenAuth } = this.props;
     console.log(tokenAuth);      // 'undefined'
     console.log({tokenAuth});      // 'token: undefined'
    ...
```

Actions:

```
    const LOGIN_REQUEST  = 'LOGIN_REQUEST ';
const LOGIN_ERROR = 'LOGIN_ERROR';
const LOGIN_SUCCESS= 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';

export const setLoginPending = () => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_REQUEST,
    };
};

export const setLoginSuccess = (tokenAuth) => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        tokenAuth,
    };
};

export const setLoginError = (loginError) => {
    return {
        type: LOGIN_ERROR,
        loginError
    }
};

export function authorization(email, password) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(setLoginPending());
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://myrmic.geos.tom.ru:2180/v1/auth',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept' : 'application/json'
            },
            data: {
                ur_email: email = 'super@user.mc',
                ur_password: password = '123456',
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                dispatch(setLoginSuccess(response.data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                dispatch(setLoginError(error));
            })
    };
}
```

Reducer:

```
export default function authReducer(state = {
    tokenAuth: false,
    isLoginPending: false,
    loginError: null,
}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoginPending: true,
            };
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                tokenAuth: action.tokenAuth,
                isLoginPending: false,
            };
        case LOGIN_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoginPending: false,
                loginError: action.loginError
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run `mapStateToProps()` and where do you run `authorization` ?

Comment: See https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html try placing a `debugger` in the actions, reducers, and before and after the dispatches. Drop into the repl to view the state and props. You should be able to step through and verify each step of the event handling attached to the component. It might become more clear, plus it's a good skill to have. Fwiw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `response` axios success callback. Looks like `response.data` is `undefined`

```
.then((response) => {
    dispatch(setLoginSuccess(response.data))
})
```